# PCRE get match position without getting all matches

Tags: c, regex, text, pcre

I am using pcre_exec to apply some regexps that I read from a file. Since the regexps may contain repeat counts, like `[a-z]{1000}`, I would have to pass a match vector of 3*1001 integers to obtain even the first element, which tells me where the match starts/ends.

I only need the start/end positions, not all the match (group) positions. And `pcre_exec` returns 0 which according to the manual means "you need a larger match vector".

My question is, how to I get the start/end without passing an arbitrarily large match vector. Or at least, how do I know how large a vector I need to pass.

Answer (score 0):

0 means, you have a successful match, but the ovector is too small. Only about the 2/3 entries will be filled with real values. The only exception is the first two values, which will be filled if ovector size is >= 2. Hence just pass an 'int ovector[2]' to get the start and end.

Two notes:

a) if you pass a small ovector, PCRE will allocate one, which size is enough. See this comment:

/* If the expression has got more back references than the offsets supplied can hold, we get a temporary chunk of working store to use during the matching. Otherwise, we can use the vector supplied, rounding down its size to a multiple of 3. */

You cannot reduce the memory consumption of your software this way.

b) This does not introduce any capturing brackets: [a-z]{1000}, so you don't need to pass an array with 3*1001 values. Even ([a-z]{1000}) or ([a-z]){1000} adds only one capturing bracket.

Comment: Regarding your second question (sorry I missed it), pass PCRE_INFO_CAPTURECOUNT to pcre_fullinfo to retreive the number of capturing brackets.

Comment: So you're saying the 0 I get from pcre_exec means something else in my case (other than "3 entries is too few"). I did give pcre_exec a 3-entry ovector, FWIW.